# VB.NET Multi language program

Tags: vb.net, multilingual, right-to-left

I want to create a vb.net multi language program.
I did it with `LOCALIZED=TRUE` and changing `LANGUAGE` to my lang.
But the problem is my language is right to left.

The problem is that in my language the labels beside of the text boxes are in the right side and after changing to *English* they must come to left.

How to do this?

Comment: Just set the two RightToLeft properties of the form to True.  They are localized as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you just want to change the formatting so that it writes Right to Left or you want to change the position of the labels itself?

Why not try something like this?

```
if (language = "English") Then
    label1.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No
    label1.Location = New Point(100,200)   'to change the location if required
Else If (language = "Japanese") Then
    label1.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes
    label1.Location = New Point(400,200)   'adjust the points as required
End If
```

Feel free to enlighten me in case this doesn't answer your question.

Ken